# Django Admin Deleting All Records Bad Request [400]

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, apache2

I'm trying to delete multiple records in Django Admin. If I select a page of 1000 rows and delete, I get Bad Request [400] error.

**Bad Request (400)**

Deleting rows individually works.

This is only occurring in production. I am hesitant to turn debug to True.

Model objects I am trying to delete:

```
class Case(models.Model):
    caseId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    dataCheckContactId = models.ForeignKey(DataCheckContact, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING , related_name="dchk")
    caseDteProg = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    caseIntComplete = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True, default = 0)
    caseDteStart = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    caseType = models.CharField(null = True, max_length = 36, blank=True)
    caseInputJSON = models.TextField(null = True, blank=True) # data prior to submission
    caseReturnJSON = models.TextField(null = True, blank=True) #submission data
    caseIntStatus = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True, default = 0) 
    caseBPMUuid = models.CharField(null = True, max_length = 36, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caseBPMUuid
```

Is turning Debug to True to only way to see any error messages?

Thanks

Edit 1. Using Apache2 as web-server. Possible request size bottleneck? Each row is about 20KB if pasted to a text file.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [default setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-number-fields) in Django about the number of parameters that can be submitted in one request (both POST and GET), which is set to 1000 by default.

So if you want to be able to submit more than 1000 parameters at once, change `settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS` to a higher value.

Or just avoid changing so many rows at the same time, use a custom action or bulk command to do it.

Also, when this happens, an error is raised and logged (assuming you have setup logging correctly). So checking your Django logs on your server would have enabled you to see this as a `SuspiciousOperation` exception.

Comment: Does the same apply using the Django admin interface?

Comment: Yes also admin. It’s implemented in the middleware so which app receives the request isn’t relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that your web server is hitting a limit for the size of request.  You could try fewer rows to pin this down.  500, 100, 2?  Depending on your server there will be a way to increase the maximum size.

Comment: thanks for the idea. Using apache2. I will investigate